# How to retrieve records based on multiple bit of strings present in those records?

Tags: sql, search, search-engine, where-clause

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and the MySQL database. I have a database table containing data as-like the following (note: the `column1` contains comma separated strings):

```
id   | column1                          | column2 | columnM    
-----|-----------------------------------------------------
1    | one1                             | value1  |  ...
2    | one1, two1                       | value1  |  ...
3    | one1, two1, three1               | value1  |  ...
4    | one2                             | value2  |  ...
5    | one2, two2                       | value2  |  ...
6    | one2, two2, three2               | value2  |  ...
...  | ...                              | ...     |  ...
1000 | oneN                             | valueN  |  ...
1001 | oneN, twoN                       | valueN  |  ...
1002 | oneN, twoN, threeN               | valueN  |  ...
1003 | oneN, twoN, threeN, fourN        | valueN  |  ...
```

I would like to write a SQL query so to retrieve *records starting at the same time with one or more bit of strings* present in the `column1`. That is, for instance, given I search the `column1` for *strings*

```
Case 1: "thr"
Case 2: "two1 thr"
Case 3: "two thr"
Case 4: "wo"
Case 5: "one"
Case 6: "four one"
```

Then, I would like to get respectively records with following `id`s:

```
Case 1: 3, 6, 1002, 1003                         # returns all records starting with "thr"
Case 2: 3                                        # returns all records starting with "two1" and at the same time starting with "thr" 
Case 3: 3, 6, 1002, 1003                         # returns all records starting with "two" and at the same time starting with "thr"
Case 4:                                          # nothing to return
Case 5: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003 # returns all records starting with "one"
Case 6: 1003                                     # returns all records starting with "four" and at the same time starting with "one"
```

*How can I make the SQL query to behave as the above* (maybe, by using something as like wildcards or other things unknown to me)*?* Since I am trying to implement a "simple" search engine, what do you advice about? Is there some prescriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the LIKE clause, i.e. Case 2:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBL
 WHERE 1
   AND CONCAT(', ', column1) LIKE '%, two1%'
   AND CONCAT(', ', column1) LIKE '%, thr%'
```

The trick here is that you want to make sure that the string being searched is the beginning of one of the comma separated items, hence the leading `,` (comma-space). This doesn't exist for the first item, so we `CONCAT()` it to the column, turning `one, two1` => `, one, two1`.  The LIKE pattern can then properly work.

The `WHERE 1` is a pattern to "consume" the seed the WHERE clause with one condition, so that for each word you need to search by, you can add an **AND** expression

```
   AND CONCAT(', ', column1) LIKE '%, someword%'
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to reflect the behavior I am looking for.

Comment: Can you check it again, I have added an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the *case 6* where search strings are provided in an unsorted order. See the updated question.

Comment: It still works. The trick is that you have to SPLIT the *string* in Ruby and create the `AND CONCAT.. LIKE ..` clauses. I'd give you the code in a splitsecond if it were PHP/C#